# filterStart SEVERE: Exception starting filter Authentication Filter java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, alfresco, alfresco-share, catalina

I try to install alfresco on Rocky Linux. When I execute startup.sh I see in logs catalina.out this error:

```
Apr 11, 2023 2:40:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter Authentication Filter
java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    No such file or directory
    at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:137)
    at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile.<init>(ConfigFile.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:255)
    at javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:247)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.Configuration.getConfiguration(Configuration.java:246)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$1.run(LoginContext.java:245)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$1.run(LoginContext.java:243)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:243)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:417)
    at org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.SSOAuthenticationFilter.init(SSOAuthenticationFilter.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5542)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
    No such file or directory
    at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:335)
    at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:293)
    at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:135)
    ... 32 more
```

I don't know where this file should be, what should I add. How can I fix this?

I tried following instruction with installation but it doesnt work. I also search in Internet about this problem but its uncommon error.

Comment: Hello, 
Can you tell me what is your authentication chain please ? (see this in alfresco-global.properties)
Thank's

Comment: Idk, but I fixed it by changing name of file java.conf to java.config.